# JavaScript, move an image on another

Tags: javascript

I want to move an image on another one. I saw on forum, the best way to do this is to use `destination.appendChild(elementToMove)`. But when I use it, my `elementToMove` just disappears.

Here is a fiddle for what I want to do (but that's not working):

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0o7x7dyo/)

Here is my JS Code:

```
var body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
var td_sign = document.getElementById("sign");
var td_moon = document.getElementById("moon");

var sign = document.createElement("img");
sign.src="http://img11.hostingpics.net/thumbs/mini_723286sign.png";

var moon = document.createElement("img");
moon.src="http://img11.hostingpics.net/thumbs/mini_418048moon.png";

td_sign.appendChild(sign);
td_moon.appendChild(moon);

var testbutton = document.createElement('input');
testbutton.type='button';
testbutton.value='test';
testbutton.onclick = function(){
  sign.appendChild(moon);
}
body.appendChild(testbutton);
```

I just want to use JavaScript.

Comment: *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve].*

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/0o7x7dyo/3/ ??

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown if it's an answer, you just exchange position of two elements, not put one on another. So it's not what I looking for.

Comment: You wan to put them visually one over another? You don't mean on the only on the DOM? If yes, your problem then is not javascript but CSS instead..

Comment: Of course ! how an image can be on another not visually ? And yes it's can be CSS problem but it's dynamic move so i need javascript for doing that. I find a way to get position of my background image then set position of my second with that but it's not really beautifull code.

Comment: Please edit your question to include the javascript code in the question. You can _also_ link to the fiddle if necessary.